# Check if input value is equal to unknown number of words list which comes from data attribute

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I am making simple, basic validation of words, but somehow it does not work. This is what i have:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="customfixer">
   <li data-folder="something">something</li>
   <li data-folder="random name">random name</li>
   <li data-folder="my news">my news</li>
   <!-- etc.. 100+ more of unique folder names -->
</div>

<input type="submit" class="submitasvalid" name="submit" value="Create folder" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input.newfoldername').on('input', function() {

  var lopinys = $('input.newfoldername').val();

  $('.customfixer').each(function() {

    var validacija = $(this).find('li').data('folder');

    if(lopinys == validacija) {
      // alert if folder name exists in the list
    }
    else{
      // alert if folder name does not exists in the list
    }

  });

});
```

I know that something is bad, because sometimes it works, but sometimes it does not.

**Question:**

How to check, if input value is equal to unknown number of words list which comes from data attribute? And if equal - do something.

Thanks for any answers and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for the existence of a `data-*` attribute with a given on a set of elements you could use `filter()` and check the `length` of the result set. Try this:

```
$('input.newfoldername').on('input', function() {
    var lopinys = $('input.newfoldername').val();

    $('.customfixer').each(function() {
        var exists = $(this).find('li').filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('folder') == lopinys;
        }).length != 0;

        if (exists) {
            console.log(lopinys + ' exists');
        } else {
            console.log(lopinys + ' does not exist');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pnuhjawb/)

Comment: Hmm. Strange, your example works as expected. But in my code, it launches as many times as folder names exists. For example, 40. Basicly, it checks if first check is valid or not, not everything. But your example works as expected :)

Comment: Yep, it grabs only the last data attribute in the list :/

Comment: That sounds odd. Could you update your jsFiddle so that it has the same behaviour?

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check input value when submit button is clicked. If that is the case try following :

HTML :

```
<div class="customfixer">
   <li data-folder="something">something</li>
   <li data-folder="random name">random name</li>
   <li data-folder="my news">my news</li>
   // etc.. 100+ more of unique folder names
</div>
<input type="text" name="input-name" class="newfoldername" />
<input type="submit" class="submitasvalid" name="submit" value="Create folder" />
```

jQuery :

```
   $('input.submitasvalid').on('click', function() {

  var lopinys = $('input.newfoldername').val(); // you must have

  $('.customfixer li').each(function() {

var validacija = $(this).find('li').attr('data-folder');

if(lopinys === validacija) {
    alert('Value matches with input');
  // alert if folder name exists in the list
}
else{
    alert('Value does not match with input');
  // alert if folder name does not exists in the list
}

 });

});
```

Comment: No, i want to check if name exists on "keypress". In my situation ``.on('input' function() {``

Comment: try keyup or keydown instead of input

$('input.newfoldername').on('keyup', function() {
//code
});